# Silverlight light dropdown

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a Silverlight form that contains a Stack Panel (orientation = vertical) with 10 rows.  Each row contains a TextBlock and Textbox control except the last row has a TextBlock and Drowdown..  At the bottom of the control are two buttons.  Previous & Continue.

There are 10 items in the Dropdown.  When I select a value from the Dropdown, only two of the ten items are showing up.  I believe that the remaining items aren't displying because there's some sort of clipping effect going on.  Fair enough.

Does Silverlight allow the dropdown control to display upwards (instead of the default down direction)?  Will I have to override some rendering capabiliities before the dropdown is rendered to the control or is there a property that allows me to accomplish this functionality?

Comment: Show us some XAML, the dropdown usually knows it doesn't have enough room and would automatically appear above the input area instead of below.

Comment: You're 100% correct, I just realized that this is a custom control written by another developer.  Since this is proprietary, I'll have to ask him.  But thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

The Silverlight ComboBox auto aligns the dropdown popup to always be visible whenever possible.
all Popup based controls (ComboBox, AutoCompleteBox, DatePicker and TimePicker) all have this feature enabled.

So if there's not enough screen real-estate below the ComboBox to show the dropdown popup, it'll show up above the control. 
The combobox nesting in the visual tree should not affect the dropdown popup auto alignment.  The internal Popup control (inside the ComboBox) ignores the Visual Tree and is nested "above" the visual tree.

If you have specific issues, please share **minimal and relevant** XAML. Since Keith is on this thread, I think it's safe to say he'll log a bug if needed.